Is it possible to implement `any` with retrieving the base class?
Disclaimer: This question is rather hypothetical, and I personally would just use an abstract interface instead.
As I understand, std::any_cast<T> has an overload that accepts a pointer to std::any and returns a pointer to T, if it is contained within, otherwise nullptr.
This behavior is similar to dynamic_cast, but is rather limited, since dynamic_cast allows upcast and downcast to any class of the inheritance chain.
But this is impossible with std::any_cast: one has to first explicitly cast to a contained object and then, for example, perform a static_cast to the base class. This limits the value of std::any for polymorphic usage.
So, would it be possible to have a non-UB safe implementation of any that allows getting a pointer to a base class?

A non-safe implementation of any is just a void pointer.

@FrançoisAndrieux that's not the question. std::any_cast can get a pointer to the class itself, but not to any of the non-private base classes, like dynamic_cast can. It's just dynamic_cast relies on RTTI (which could be disabled)

No, and it's a gross misuse of std::any. dynamic_cast relies heavily on compiler magic and is completely unwritable as a library.

It is possible to implement another my_any class with a dynamic_any_cast, to detect polymorphic hierarchy. But it's a long shot. Doing it takes away some life force. Decorating std::any to constraint the set of it's values is easier, but I don't like it; it's a stack of 2 layers of type erasure; very inefficient. There's also this boost.type_erasure.any with a very unorthodox syntax; you'd need to use macros and counterintuitive constructs.

Yes and no.
It is possible to write an any implementation that supports dynamic_cast for all non-final classes.
But it is impossible (at least without shenanigans) to write one that works with all types.

To use dynamic_cast we need a pointer to any class within the inheritance hierarchy of a type - a void* pointer is not sufficient.
(at least without relying on either UB, implementation details or help from the compiler ¹)
So there are two viable options for an any implementation:

mandate a common base class, e.g.:
// only subtypes of object can be stored in any
class object { public: virtual ~object() = default; /* for rtti */ };

class any {
    std::unique_ptr<object> ptr;

    /* ... */
};

/* ... */

template<class T>
T* dynamic_any_cast(any* a) {
    if(a == nullptr || a->ptr == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(a->ptr);
}




Pros
Cons




Easy to implement
Only subtypes of object are supported - so scalar types and unrelated classes can't be storedBasically equivalent to std::unique_ptr<object>, so not worth the effort.







inherit from the stored value, e.g.:
class any_holder_base {
    bool is_normal_class;
    virtual ~any_holder_base() = default;
    /* ... */
};

template<class T>
concept is_inheritable = std::is_class_v<std::remove_cv_t<T>> && 
                         !std::is_final_v<std::remove_cv_t<T>>;

template<class T>
// holder class for scalar values, unions, final classes, etc...
class any_holder final : public any_holder_base {
    T value;
    any_holder(T const& v): any_holder_base{false}, value{v} {}
    /* ... */
};

// specialization for "normal" class types
//          v
template<is_inheritable T>
// inherit from the value                              ----v
class any_holder<T> final : public any_holder_base, public T {
    any_holder(T const& v): any_holder_base{true}, T{v} {}
    /* ... */
};

class any {
     std::unique_ptr<any_holder_base> value;
     /* ... */
};

template<class T>
T* dynamic_any_cast(any* a) {
    if(a == nullptr || !!a->value)
        return nullptr;

    if(a->type() == typeid(T))
        return (T*)a->value->get_value_pointer();

    // we didn't inherit from the value
    // (either because it's a scalar, union or final class, etc...)
    if(!a->value->is_normal_class)
        return nullptr;

    // cast the any_holder_base* pointer directly -
    // by inheriting from T it is part of the inheritance hierarchy,
    // so dynamic_cast'ing to it works
    return dynamic_cast<T*>(a->value.get());
}




Pros
Cons




Same interface as std::any is possibleCan store all types, including scalars, unions, etc...
final classes can be stored, but do not support dynamic_casting, which might be unexpectedRequires quite a bit more codevirtual functions defined by any_holder_base could accidentally be overriden by the stored value






I personally think that inheriting from the stored value is the only sensible approach - it allows for an interface that is equivalent to std::any and storing arbitrary types.
The only big drawback is that it doesn't work if the stored type is final, but storing those could easily be prevented by sprinkling a few static_asserts in the any implementation.
e.g.:
template<class T>
any::any(T&& value) {
    // disallow final classes to be stored in any
    using U = std::remove_cvref_t<T>;
    static_assert(!std::is_class_v<U> || !std::is_final_v<U>);
    
    value = std::make_unique<any_holder<U>>(value);
}


Full implementation
Here's a full implementation of any with dynamic_any_cast implemented: godbolt with examples
#include <typeinfo>
#include <memory>
#include <any>
#include <type_traits>

namespace impl {
    // small any object optimization
    // small objects are stored inline in the any object, without dynamic allocation
    // these two options control the size and alignment of the buffer within the any object.
    // can be tuned if necessary
    constexpr std::size_t any_inline_buffer_size = sizeof(void*) * 2;
    constexpr std::size_t any_inline_buffer_align = alignof(void*);

    template<class T>
    concept is_inheritable = std::is_class_v<std::remove_cv_t<T>> && !std::is_final_v<std::remove_cv_t<T>>;

    template<class T>
    inline constexpr bool is_in_place_type_t_v = false;
    template<class T>
    inline constexpr bool is_in_place_type_t_v<std::in_place_type_t<T>> = true;

    [[noreturn]] inline void throw_bad_any_cast() {
    #if __cpp_exceptions
        throw std::bad_any_cast{};
    #else
        std::abort();
    #endif
    }

    class any_holder_base {
    protected:
        any_holder_base() = default;
        any_holder_base(any_holder_base const&) = delete;
        any_holder_base(any_holder_base&&) = delete;
        any_holder_base& operator=(any_holder_base const&) = delete;
        any_holder_base& operator=(any_holder_base&&) = delete;

    public:
        virtual ~any_holder_base() = default;

        virtual const std::type_info& any_impl_type() const noexcept = 0;
        virtual void* any_impl_pointer() noexcept = 0;
        virtual bool any_impl_can_use_dynamic_cast() const noexcept = 0;

        virtual any_holder_base* any_impl_copy_to(void* inline_storage) const = 0;
        virtual any_holder_base* any_impl_move_to(void* inline_storage) noexcept = 0;
    };

    template<class T>
    class any_holder;

    template<class T>
    constexpr bool is_any_inline_storable = (
        alignof(any_holder<T>) <= any_inline_buffer_align &&
        sizeof(any_holder<T>) <= any_inline_buffer_size &&
        std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T>
    );

    template<class T>
    class any_holder final : public any_holder_base {
    private:
        T value;

    public:
        template<class... Args>
        any_holder(Args&&... args): value(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

        const std::type_info& any_impl_type() const noexcept final {
            return typeid(T);
        }
        
        void* any_impl_pointer() noexcept final {
            return &value;
        }

        bool any_impl_can_use_dynamic_cast() const noexcept final {
            return false;
        }

        any_holder_base* any_impl_copy_to(void* inline_storage) const final {
            if constexpr(is_any_inline_storable<T>)
                return new(inline_storage) any_holder(value);
            else
                return new any_holder(value);
        }

        any_holder_base* any_impl_move_to(void* inline_storage) noexcept final {
            if constexpr(is_any_inline_storable<T>)
                return new(inline_storage) any_holder(std::move(value));
            else
                return nullptr;
        }
    };

    template<is_inheritable T>
    class any_holder<T> final : public any_holder_base, public T {
    public:
        template<class... Args>
        any_holder(Args&&... args): T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

        const std::type_info& any_impl_type() const noexcept final {
            return typeid(T);
        }
        
        void* any_impl_pointer() noexcept final {
            return static_cast<T*>(this);
        }

        bool any_impl_can_use_dynamic_cast() const noexcept final {
            return true;
        }

        any_holder_base* any_impl_copy_to(void* inline_storage) const final {
            if constexpr(is_any_inline_storable<T>)
                return new(inline_storage) any_holder(*static_cast<const T*>(this));
            else
                return new any_holder(*static_cast<const T*>(this));
        }

        any_holder_base* any_impl_move_to(void* inline_storage) noexcept final {
            if constexpr(is_any_inline_storable<T>)
                return new(inline_storage) any_holder(std::move(*static_cast<T*>(this)));
            else
                return nullptr; 
        }
    };

    template<class T, bool try_dynamic, class Any>
    inline T* do_any_cast(Any* a) noexcept {
        if(!a)
            return nullptr;

        if(!a->has_value())
            return nullptr;

        // direct match
        if(a->type() == typeid(T))
            return static_cast<T*>(a->value->any_impl_pointer());

        // try dynamic_cast
        if constexpr(try_dynamic && is_inheritable<T>) {
            if(!a->value->any_impl_can_use_dynamic_cast())
                return nullptr;

            return dynamic_cast<T*>(a->value);
        }

        return nullptr;
    }
}

class any {
private:
    impl::any_holder_base* value;
    alignas(impl::any_inline_buffer_align) std::byte inline_buffer[impl::any_inline_buffer_size];

    bool is_stored_inline() {
        return static_cast<void*>(value) == static_cast<void*>(inline_buffer);
    }

    template<class Type, class... Args>
    void emplace_impl(Args&&... args) {
        if constexpr(impl::is_any_inline_storable<Type>)
            value = new(inline_buffer) impl::any_holder<Type>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        else
            value = new impl::any_holder<Type>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template<class T, bool try_dynamic, class Any>
    friend inline T* impl::do_any_cast(Any* a) noexcept;

public:
    constexpr any() noexcept : value(nullptr) {}

    any(any const& other) {
        value = other.has_value() ?
                      other.value->any_impl_copy_to(inline_buffer)
                    : nullptr;
    }

    any(any&& other) noexcept {
        if(other.is_stored_inline()) {
            value = other.value->any_impl_move_to(inline_buffer);
            other.reset();
        } else {
           value = other.value;
           other.value = nullptr;
        }
    }

    template<class ValueType>
    requires (
        !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>, any> &&
        std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>> &&
        !impl::is_in_place_type_t_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>>
    )
    any(ValueType&& value) {
        emplace_impl<std::decay_t<ValueType>>(std::forward<ValueType>(value));
    }

    template<class ValueType, class... Args>
    requires (
        std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>> &&
        std::is_constructible_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>, Args...>
    )
    explicit any(std::in_place_type_t<ValueType>, Args&&... args) {
        emplace_impl<std::decay_t<ValueType>>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template<class ValueType, class U, class... Args>
    requires (
        std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>> &&
        std::is_constructible_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>, std::initializer_list<U>&, Args...>
    )
    explicit any(std::in_place_type_t<ValueType>, std::initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args) {
        emplace_impl<std::decay_t<ValueType>>(il, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    ~any() noexcept { reset(); }

    any& operator=(any const& other) {
        *this = any(other);
        return *this;
    }

    any& operator=(any&& other) noexcept {
        if(this == &other)
            return *this;
         
        reset();
        if(other.is_stored_inline()) {
            value = other.value->any_impl_move_to(inline_buffer);
            other.reset();
        } else {
           value = other.value;
           other.value = nullptr;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    template<class ValueType>
    requires(
        !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>, any> &&
        std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>>
    )
    any& operator=(ValueType&& value) {
        *this = any(std::forward<ValueType>(value));
        return *this;
    }

    const std::type_info& type() const noexcept {
        if(!value)
            return typeid(void);

        return value->any_impl_type();
    }

    bool has_value() const noexcept {
        return value != nullptr;
    }

    void swap(any& other) noexcept {
        if(!has_value() && !other.has_value())
            return;
        
        if(has_value() && other.has_value()) {
            any tmp = std::move(other);
            other = std::move(*this);
            *this = std::move(tmp);
            return;
        }
        
        // one has a value, the other doesn't
        any& full = has_value() ? *this : other;
        any& empty = has_value() ? other : *this;
        empty = std::move(full); 
    }

    void reset() noexcept {
        if(!has_value())
            return;

        if(is_stored_inline())
            value->~any_holder_base();
        else
            delete value;

        value = nullptr;
    }

    template<class ValueType, class... Args>
    requires(
        std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>> &&
        std::is_constructible_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>, Args...>
    )
    std::decay_t<ValueType>& emplace(Args&&... args) {
        reset();
        emplace_impl<std::decay_t<ValueType>>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return *static_cast<std::decay_t<ValueType>*>(value->any_impl_pointer());
    }

    template<class ValueType, class U, class... Args>
    requires(
        std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>> &&
        std::is_constructible_v<std::decay_t<ValueType>, std::initializer_list<U>&, Args...>
    )
    std::decay_t<ValueType>& emplace(std::initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args) {
        reset();
        emplace_impl<std::decay_t<ValueType>>(il, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return *static_cast<std::decay_t<ValueType>*>(value->any_impl_pointer());
    }
};

inline void swap(any& lhs, any& rhs) noexcept {
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}

template<class T, class... Args>
inline any make_any(Args&&... args) {
    return any(std::in_place_type<T>, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<class T, class U, class... Args>
inline any make_any(std::initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args) {
    return any(std::in_place_type<T>, il, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<class ValueType>
inline ValueType any_cast(any const& a) {
    using Type = std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>;
    static_assert(std::is_reference_v<ValueType> || std::is_copy_constructible_v<ValueType>);
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<ValueType, const Type&>);
    
    const Type* ptr = impl::do_any_cast<Type, false>(&a);
    if(ptr != nullptr)
        return static_cast<ValueType>(*ptr);

    impl::throw_bad_any_cast();
}

template<class ValueType>
inline ValueType dynamic_any_cast(any const& a) {
    using Type = std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>;
    static_assert(std::is_reference_v<ValueType> || std::is_copy_constructible_v<ValueType>);
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<ValueType, const Type&>);
    
    const Type* ptr = impl::do_any_cast<Type, true>(&a);
    if(ptr != nullptr)
        return static_cast<ValueType>(*ptr);

    impl::throw_bad_any_cast();
}

template<class ValueType>
inline ValueType any_cast(any& a) {
    using Type = std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>;
    static_assert(std::is_reference_v<ValueType> || std::is_copy_constructible_v<ValueType>);
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<ValueType, Type&>);
    
    Type* ptr = impl::do_any_cast<Type, false>(&a);
    if(ptr != nullptr)
        return static_cast<ValueType>(*ptr);

    impl::throw_bad_any_cast();
}

template<class ValueType>
inline ValueType dynamic_any_cast(any& a) {
    using Type = std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>;
    static_assert(std::is_reference_v<ValueType> || std::is_copy_constructible_v<ValueType>);
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<ValueType, Type&>);
    
    Type* ptr = impl::do_any_cast<Type, true>(&a);
    if(ptr != nullptr)
        return static_cast<ValueType>(*ptr);

    impl::throw_bad_any_cast();
}

template<class ValueType>
inline ValueType any_cast(any&& a) {
    using Type = std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>;
    static_assert(std::is_reference_v<ValueType> || std::is_copy_constructible_v<ValueType>);
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<ValueType, Type>);

    Type* ptr = impl::do_any_cast<Type, false>(&a);
    if(ptr != nullptr)
        return static_cast<ValueType>(std::move(*ptr));

    impl::throw_bad_any_cast();
}

template<class ValueType>
inline ValueType dynamic_any_cast(any&& a) {
    using Type = std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>;
    static_assert(std::is_reference_v<ValueType> || std::is_copy_constructible_v<ValueType>);
    static_assert(std::is_constructible_v<ValueType, Type>);

    Type* ptr = impl::do_any_cast<Type, true>(&a);
    if(ptr != nullptr)
        return static_cast<ValueType>(std::move(*ptr));

    impl::throw_bad_any_cast();
}

template<class ValueType>
inline const ValueType* any_cast(const any* a) noexcept {
    using Type = std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>;
    static_assert(!std::is_void_v<ValueType>);
    
    if(a == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    const Type* ptr = impl::do_any_cast<Type, false>(a);
    return static_cast<const ValueType*>(ptr);
}

template<class ValueType>
inline const ValueType* dynamic_any_cast(const any* a) noexcept {
    using Type = std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>;
    static_assert(!std::is_void_v<ValueType>);
    
    if(a == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    const Type* ptr = impl::do_any_cast<Type, true>(a);
    return static_cast<const ValueType*>(ptr);
}

template<class ValueType>
inline ValueType* any_cast(any* a) noexcept {
    using Type = std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>;
    static_assert(!std::is_void_v<ValueType>);
    
    if(a == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    Type* ptr = impl::do_any_cast<Type, false>(a);
    return static_cast<ValueType*>(ptr);
}

template<class ValueType>
inline ValueType* dynamic_any_cast(any* a) noexcept {
    using Type = std::remove_cvref_t<ValueType>;
    static_assert(!std::is_void_v<ValueType>);
    
    if(a == nullptr)
        return nullptr;

    Type* ptr = impl::do_any_cast<Type, true>(a);
    return static_cast<ValueType*>(ptr);
}

godbolt

Footnotes



If relying on implementation details is allowed then it's easy — it's even possible to hack dynamic_cast support onto the existing std::any implementation: godbolt example




one of the points for std::any was that it doesn't rely on rtti, unlike dynamic_cast. So having dynamic_cast in the implementation really defeats the purpose. If there was reflection, one could just check the type "id" of the type and static cast to it if it is one the bases the original type can be casted to.

@SergeyKolesnik It's true that std::any can be implemented without RTTI - but only with the caveat that it won't work across shared libraries. (std::any without RTTI has to rely on comparing the address of a templated entity - which is only guaranteed to be unique within one linked binary)

For that reason all 3 major standard libraries do use RTTI if its enabled for their std::any implementation: MSVC STL - clang libc++ - gcc libstdc++ .

@SergeyKolesnik If C++ would have some sort of compile type reflection to get all unambiguous public base classes of a given type (e.g. std::bases N2965 or std::meta::bases_of P2996R0) then it would indeed be possible to not rely on dynamic_cast (POC any godbolt). But that will need a few more years before it becomes standardized.

...and a decade before widely adopted
